# now unable to get IP address from DHCP on modem - what changed?

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have a DSL modem which does DHCP which seems to be healthy because I can connect other hosts to it and get IP addresses, but not my normal computer.

After being away for week, when booting up, it couldn't obtain an IP address. I then tried it all again and it did get an IP address, however it was really slow  or dropping most of the packets and I couldn't use it for web browsing.

Further reboots and ifdown/ifup cycles just fail outright now.

I know it's not the modem or the cable because other PCs can connect.

I don't think it's the NIC because I have a 2nd NIC that also won't obtain an IP address.

I disabled the firewall too which didn't help.

It's running 16.04.3

My only guess is that I upgraded a networking package that now requires some tweaking - dhclient perhaps. I'm not running network-manager, this is quite a basic config.

There's nothing in the logs except something along the lines of this (copied from the screen by hand):

```
Sep 8  23:40:27 gondor kernel: [ 495.11235] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
Sep 8  23:40:27 gondor kernel: [ 495.11235] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Down
```

which repeats several times while ifup is running.

Could I have trashed my network config by installing or upgrading a package?

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s25
allow-hotplug enp0s25
iface enp0s25 inet dhcp
```

**[UPDATE]** `lshw -C network` output as requested:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82567LF Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 03
       serial: 00:01:80:76:c5:39
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=1.8-3 ip=86.139.80.140 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:25 memory:fdfc0000-fdfdffff memory:fdfff000-fdffffff ioport:fe00(size=32)
```

Comment: Is this a gigabit wireless router? Your link is only 100mbit. Have you power cycled the router?

Comment: yes many times. The problem is made more despairing because initially  it sometimes came to life and  worked for an hour. Then it dies again. So I waste a lot of time hoping.

Comment: Is this a gigabit router? Connect the ethernet cable from the computer directly to your cable/dsl modem, bypassing the router, power cycle the modem, reboot the computer, and see if the problem still occurs. Then let me see `sudo lshw -C network`. Edit that output into your question please.

Comment: don't really want to type in the whole output from the other computer. It says `product: 82567LF Gigabit Network Connection` and `capacity: 1Gbit/s`. Does that help? The hardware hasn't changed though - unless you count 'breaking' as change :O - it has worked for years until now.

Comment: Re: plugging the modem straight into the computer, that is how it is anyway. Rebooting & power-cycling attempted x10

Comment: Ah yes... no router, and you have DSL. What is your MTU set for? If you're not running network-manager, what are you running? If your other computers have a gigabit link, then you've probably got a bad cable on this computer, as it's only making a 100mbit link. Make sure you use a cat 5E or 6 cable.

Comment: is there reason to believe this is the issue rather than a symptom? I have used this  hardware for years in this config  without problem. MTU is configured by the modem dhcp offer to 1492 but I have `post-up /sbin/ifconfig enp0s25 mtu 1500` in `/etc/network/interfaces` normally. I've tried  it with  the setting and with it  commented out. No difference. And the network cable seems fine, since plugging the modem directly into the other laptops allows me to connect to the net.

Comment: 1492 sounds about right for DSL, but without actually doing the proper ping testing, it may not be. Don't comment out your post-up command, but rather, change 1500 to 1492, reboot, retest. Also, check your cables for cat 5E or 6, 'cause you're not getting a gig link.

Comment: found another line in syslog between the `enp0s25 up/down` entries, saying `e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO`. Also, found and tried another gigabit type 5E cable. No change. That e1000e driver is really busy. It spits  out those `up/down` log entries every 2 secs.

Comment: Does your modem have multiple ethernet ports? If so, try another port. Check for better link speed, and no up/down entries in syslog. Did you change your MTU and then disconnect/reconnect?

Comment: Dug out an old DSL modem and hooked it up - worked first time. Can't draw any conclusions from this whole mess except that it will probably happen again soon. This is with MTU set back to 1500. And the logs are still showing 100Mbps, not 1Gbps. Frustratingly, the other NIC still doesn't work (hadn't mentioned that yet - starting a new Q for that.

Comment: I've added an answer that shows how to properly test for MTU settings... as 1500 is clearly wrong. I just thought of something... show me `sudo lshw -C network` I want to see if you have r8169 cards.

Comment: Your `lshw` looks fine. You don't have the r8168 card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the MTU setting for your DSL connection.

**For DSL, a common MTU setting is 1492. Just go ahead and try this value first and see if your web sites are now accessible.**

To determine the correct setting, start with all MTU settings = 1500 and VPN = off. (VPN requires different testing).

In terminal:

```
ping [-c count] [-M do] [-s packet_size] [host]
```

The options used are:

- `c count`: number of times to ping
- `M hint`: Select Path MTU Discovery strategy.  may be either `do` (prohibit fragmentation, even local one), `want` (do PMTU discovery, fragment locally when packet size is large), or `dont` (do not set DF flag).
- `s packet_size`: Specifies the number of data bytes to be sent.

You should always start at 1472 and work your way down by 10 each time. Once you get a reply, go up by 1 until you get a fragmented packet. Take that value (last good value) and add 28 to the value to account for the various TCP/IP headers. Eg. let's say that 1452 was the proper packet size (where you first got an ICMP reply to your ping). The actual MTU size would be 1480, which is the optimum for the network we're working with.

```
ping -c 4 -M do -s 1472 8.8.8.8 # this will probably show fragmentation

ping -c 4 -M do -s 1462 8.8.8.8 # may show fragmentation

ping -c 4 -M do -s 1452 8.8.8.8 # no fragmentation?

ping -c 4 -M do -s 1453 8.8.8.8 # still no fragmentation?
```

reference: [How to determine the proper MTU size with ICMP pings](http://muzso.hu/2009/05/17/how-to-determine-the-proper-mtu-size-with-icmp-pings)

Comment: Thanks for having the time & patience to stick with me on this! Just looked up some old emails to work out why I fixed MTU at 1500 in the first place & discovered the old modem I'm now using has an internal iptables setting in its linux kernel pegging the MTU thro the modem  to 1450. A couple of questions that would really make your answer perfect: (1) what is the max value of MTU? First you say start at 1500, then you say start at 1472. Could I start any higher? Whats the causal factor here? (2) Why is this preventing DHCP discovery? Never did before - caused other problems, but not this.

Comment: 1) the max MTU is really what your DSL modem and ISP can support. 1500 is the standard for non-DSL connections. If you notice the difference between 1500 and 1472 is 28... the number that you add to the last working ping command. And pinging at 1472 should fail, esp if your modem is pegged at 1450. 2) I can't say for sure. Something may have changed in the Ubuntu network software, or they may have updated the firmware in your original modem.

Comment: Can you please at least *try* to adapt your answer to the specifics of the question being asked? Maybe add a little explanatory text? How to change these settings? *Something* that stops the system from flagging these? We've been over this before and yes, I do see how this answers both questions, but please put in a little bit of effort to ensure they're tweaked for each question.